# Big O notation for complex-valued functions of a real variable

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$.  Is there a standard notion of $f = O(g)$?

If I had to take a stab at a definition, I'd try something like

> $f = O(g)$ provided there exists $M>0$ and $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M |g(x)|$ for all $x>x_0$.

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the complex mod.

Comment: This is right, although sometimes we're interested in behavior as $x\to 0$ rather than as $x\to\infty$. Ordinarily it is clear from the context.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like that, no problem. Even  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is on your side: it defines $f=O(g)$ as $|f|\le M|g|$ (in an appropriate domain, for some $M$).

Some people  prefer writing $f=O(|g|)$, so that the function inside of $O$ is always nonnegative. But there is no mathematical difference here, only a matter of preference.